# react 16 upgrade error issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I am trying to migrate my app from React 15.6 to React 16.2, and also replace react-router-dom from react-router, but still have some error I don't understand. please help me check it.

```
index.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:12)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 7e469d7f5710750b80d0:555)
at fn (bootstrap 7e469d7f5710750b80d0:86)
at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap 7e469d7f5710750b80d0:578)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 7e469d7f5710750b80d0:555)
at bootstrap 7e469d7f5710750b80d0:578
at bootstrap 7e469d7f5710750b80d0:578
```

Comment: React Router is complaining... The API for React Router has changed a lot from v 2 to v 4... It's impossible to tell without looking at your relevant codebase... (and that's a lot...) You should check the React Router docs...